# RecyclerView already scrolled to bottom when activity starts

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have fragments with RecyclerView in my activity, But whenever I start the fragment, the RecyclerView is already scrolled to the bottom. To load more item, user have to scroll a little bit upwards and then scroll back to the bottom, And when more items load, RecyclerView is again scrolled to the new bottom.

Here is the code in fragment.

```
public class FavouriteFragment extends Fragment{

public RecyclerView recyclerView ;
public RecyclerView.Adapter adapter ;
public LinearLayoutManager layoutManager ;

int pastVisiblesItems, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;

Constants constants;
ArrayList<CardSetterGetter> arrayList;
private List<CardSetterGetter> imagelist;
int start ;
public int end ;
boolean loading = true ;
int totalcount ;
ArrayList<String> imageNameArray ;
String androidId;
String categoryName ;
String cateGoryFlag = "false";
String url;
String tagname = "";

ArrayList<String> title ;
ProgressBar progressBar ;

TextView errormsg ;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //to hide search
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    item.setVisible(false);
}



@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.favourite_fragment,container,false);

    arrayList = new ArrayList<CardSetterGetter>();
    imageNameArray =  new ArrayList<String>();
    start = 0;
    end = start + 2 ;

    imagelist = new ArrayList<CardSetterGetter>();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    errormsg = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.error);

    getdata();

    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            if(dy > 0)
            {
                visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
                totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
                pastVisiblesItems = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                int i = visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems ;
                System.out.println(i);
                System.out.println(totalItemCount);

                if(loading) {
                    if (i == totalItemCount) {
                        loading = false ;
                        start = arrayList.size() ;
                        end = arrayList.size() + 2 ;
                        requestWithSomeHttpHeaders2(start,end);
                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() { // This thread runs in the UI
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                loading = true;
                            }
                        },2000);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    requestWithSomeHttpHeaders2(start, end);

    return view ;
}

public void requestWithSomeHttpHeaders2(int s , int e) {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

    url = "my url";

    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url ,
            new Response.Listener<String> ()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray payload = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Payload");
                        JSONObject MetaData = jsonObject.getJSONObject("MetaData");
                        System.out.println(response);
                        totalcount = MetaData.getInt("TotalCount");
                        System.out.println("200" + "    " + totalcount);
                        System.out.println("payload  length"+payload.length());

                        int i ;
                        for(i =0 ; i < payload.length() ; i++)
                        {

                            System.out.println(payload.getJSONObject(i).getString("image_title"));
                            System.out.println(payload.getJSONObject(i).getString("image_title"));
                            System.out.println(payload.getJSONObject(i).getString("image_file"));
                            System.out.println(payload.getJSONObject(i).getString("image_description"));
                            System.out.println(payload.getJSONObject(i).getString("image_category"));
                            System.out.println(payload.getJSONObject(i).getString("image_tags"));
                            System.out.println(payload.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
                            System.out.println(payload.getJSONObject(i).getString("favourite"));

                            String newString = payload.getJSONObject(i).getString("image_file").replace("original_image", "thumbnail");
                            CardSetterGetter all = new CardSetterGetter(payload.getJSONObject(i).getString("image_file"),
                                    payload.getJSONObject(i).getString("image_title"),
                                    payload.getJSONObject(i).getString("image_description"),
                                    payload.getJSONObject(i).getString("image_category"),
                                    payload.getJSONObject(i).getString("image_tags"),
                                    payload.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"),
                                    payload.getJSONObject(i).getString("favourite"));

                            System.out.println("i value is " + i);

                            arrayList.add(all);
                            Handler handler = new Handler();

                            final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),arrayList,imageNameArray,totalItemCount);
                                    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                                    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
                                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    //adapter.notifyItemInserted(arrayList.size() - 1);
                                    if (end >= totalcount)
                                    {
                                        int index = totalcount -1 ;
                                        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(index);
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(end);
                                    }
                                }
                            };

                            handler.post(r);

                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println("error" + e);

                    }

                }

            },


            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.d("ERROR","error => "+error.toString());
                    // definitions.setText("check your internet connection");
                    NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
//                        Log.e("Volley", "Error. HTTP Status Code:"+networkResponse.statusCode);
                    if (networkResponse != null) {
                        Log.e("Volley", "Error. HTTP Status Code:"+networkResponse.statusCode);
                    }

                    if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                        Log.e("Volley", "TimeoutError");
                    }else if(error instanceof NoConnectionError){
                        Log.e("Volley", "NoConnectionError");
                    } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                        Log.e("Volley", "AuthFailureError");
                    } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                        Log.e("Volley", "ServerError");
                    } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                        Log.e("Volley", "NetworkError");
                    } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                        Log.e("Volley", "ParseError");
                    }
                }

            }

    );

    queue.add(postRequest);

}
public void getdata(){
    try {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("mobileId" , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        androidId = sharedPref.getString("mobileId" , "");
        sharedPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("categoryInfo" , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        categoryName = sharedPref.getString("categoryName" , "");
        cateGoryFlag = sharedPref.getString("categoryFlag" , "");
        tagname = sharedPref.getString("tagname" , "");

    }catch (Exception e){

    }


}
}
```

I tried removing if else part of the code, but that made the recyclerView scroll to the top whenever user reach the bottom of the recyclerView.

Please tell me if you need more of the code or code of `RecyclerViewAdapter`.

Comment: Have you tried using the other Manager constructor: LinearLayoutManager(activity, orientation, reverseLayout) ? If I recall correctly, I had a similar problem with a RecyclerView and I solved it by setting the layout orientation (vertical or horizontal, whatever you need).

Comment: @EdoardoArnaudo No, I haven't tried that. And I am not sure how to do that. Can you post an answer explaining more about it

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar problem by providing the correct orientation to the layout manager. I would change your code to something like:

```
public RecyclerView.Adapter adapter ;
adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),arrayList,imageNameArray,totalItemCount);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

//This line should do the trick:
//first parameter is the context
//second parameter is the orientation
//third parameter is used for reverse layout (if you need to show items from last to first)
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

//probably better to use notifyDataSetChanged to let the adapter know you just initialized it (instead of notifying a single element)
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Not sure why you provide the total item count to the adapter as well, but that's outside the scope of the question and surely doesn't give any problems.

**EDIT:**
Now that you posted the whole fragment code, I am seeing at least a couple problems:
- the RecyclerView initialization should not be in a runnable, but in the onCreateView or some starting function. You just need to set the manager and the adapter once.
- You provide `imageNameArray` to your adapter, but where are you inserting new items into it? If you want your RecyclerView to scroll down to the last inserted item, you first need to add an item to the ArrayList, then notify the insertion at that position, something like this:

```
int position = imageNameAray.size();
imageNameArray.add(item);
adapter.notifyItemInserted(position); //this makes the view update the item in that position, making the recycler to scroll there
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but that did't worked. The recyclerView is behaving exactly as it was before the changes. Should I keep these changes even if they are not making any differece?

Comment: Yes, it's surely better to explicit the layout orientation! Perhaps it could help if you provided more code from your fragment, for instance: where do you initialize the recyclerView, how do you fetch the data... Using only that snippet might not be enough. Sidenote: avoid calling scrollToPosition manually if you can, the recycler should behave correctly if properly configured.

Comment: check out the code now. I added the code of whole fragment.

Comment: Well first of all help me understand where are you inserting items into the arrayList! You don't have to (and should not) setup the recyclerView at every step, ut instead you should initialize once, and then insert every new item in the arrayList and notify the adapter (remember you provided the arrayList reference to your adapter, so it can access the whole list already).

Comment: OK, thanks for the amount of efforts you are putting in btw.

Comment: No problem, glad to help! Just comment here if you still have any problems.

Comment: actually I am not the author of this code, I am a beginner and I have made similar app before but never did something like this.. So, i don't understand most of the codes in this app.

Comment: Well, I would suggest to start a new fresh project, or simply create an empty activity just for the purpose of testing the RecyclerView behaviour, because it is kind of tricky to use in the beginning. It is surely the way to go if you want to display lists of data, but the flexibility it provides brings more complexity in the structure.